# how to use join in sql server more efficiency?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

The SQL code takes 5 seconds to query the total answer which is about 50000 rows in the database.

How can I make my SQL query faster?

I am thinking if there are more than 6, 7, or 8 tables, it must be wasting a lot of time to query all data.
Is there a faster way to do this?

```
   select c.publishdate,
          a.id,
          a.title,
          o.name,
          a.author,
          a.createusername,
          a.createdate,
          a.pubusername,
          a.pubdate,
          b.orgid,
          c.text,
          d.channelid
     from cms_ext_news a
left join t_sys_user b on a.createuserid = b.id
left join cms_core_content c on a.id = c.id
left join t_sys_org o on o.orgid = b.orgid 
left join cms_channel d on d.channelid = '79de9baff5f94369b709d8a1ea1e9e'
```

Comment: Create indexes on all your join columns, clustered indexes if they include data you want to display.

Comment: thanks a lot,I will receive your suggestion @paqogomez

Comment: Also, based on the SQL above, you could just specify the value for d.channelid in the SELECT clause, and eliminate a join altogether.  Right now, you're essentially doing a CROSS JOIN against a single value, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Stuart Ainsworth I clear the last join and putted it into the select clause,same rows I queried,I found there are both final answer rows and the rows of cms_ext_news are same ,maybe the "channelid" is useless i thought ,but the real scense is that I want to find the clicked item(channel) on the selected treenode.I am confused.